# Python Syntax Error with test code

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
ItemName = input("Enter your item name: ")
PricePerPound = float(input("Enter the Price per pound: "))
ItemWeightPounds = float(input("Enter the weight of the item in pounds: "))
ItemWeightOunces = float(input("Enter the weight of the item in Ounces: "))
UnitPrice = (PricePerPound/16)
TotalPrice = (PricePerPound * ItemWeightPounds + ItemWeightOunces/16)
print("The Unit Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + UnitPrice)
print("The Total Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + TotalPrice)

Traceback (most recent call last):
print("The Unit Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + UnitPrice)
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

whenever I run it in python I get the above error, can anyone identify the issues with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing your `print`-statement too early.

All you want to print has to be between the brackets:

```
print("The Unit Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + str(UnitPrice))
print("The Total Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + str(TotalPrice))
```

You also need to cast your `float`- and `int`-objects to `string` because you can only concatenate (`+`) `string`-objects.

Comment: I have edited and this is the error I now get TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly                                            My last two lines:print("The Unit Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + UnitPrice)
print("The Total Price for your " + ItemName + " is: $" + TotalPrice)

Comment: Ah perfect, than you! I did not know I had to add the str.